# QGIS - convert multiple polygons to evenly spaced points within polygon boundary

Tags: qgis, polygon, convert

I need to convert the polygons in a vector layer to evenly spaced points within the polygon boundaries in QGIS. The vector file contains >1000 polygons mostly with overlaps.   The attribute data of the polygon needs to be captured in the new point table. Only extraction of the nodes is not enough.

Comment: You could convert the polygon to raster at the specified cellsize you want the points to be separated by, then convert that raster to points...

Comment: Thanks but I is not preserving all the attribute data stored with the polygons.

Comment: You could spatially join the points (from the raster) back to the polygons when you're done...